# Countdown Timer not working in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, countdowntimer

I have created countdown timer using jquery, it works fine in mozila, chorme but it is not working in internet explorer; my code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <div>Minutes</div>
 <div>Seconds</div>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script src="http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
         $('#counter').countdown({
         image: 'digits.png',
             startTime: '25:30'
         });
     });
</script>
```

please help me.

Comment: What does it say in IE's JavaScript console?

Comment: your code is working in IE 9 and 8 as http://jsfiddle.net/RxcVP/1/ , but it is not working properly in IE..Please mention that your problem related to Proper functionality in IE or visibility in IE?

Comment: Hi usman i am developing online exam site where i puted count down timer it works fine mozila,chrome but it is not working in IE6.count down digit image is not displaying in IE

Comment: Hi Viral what ever u suggested to edit i did but it is not working in IE.i am using IE6.please help me

Comment: it is better if you use http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/ , since this timer is working in IE 6.0, check out DEMO

Answer (score 0):

The `Countdown timer JS`  you are using have some syntax that are not supported in `IE 6.0` browser. So, It is better to use [This](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/) `CountDown Timer`, since it works for `IE 9.0` and other browsers

Comment: sir is there any modifiaction that i need to do in my code so that it can work on IE6